# MVVMLight Toolkit changes not reflected when property is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using the [MVVMLight Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) in my `WPF` project. All my `ViewModel`s derive from the toolkit's `ViewModelBase` class, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you and does all the notify work.

My current setup is extremely simple. I have a `Person` class with a single `Name` property.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My window has a `TextBlock` and a `Button`, and to the `TextBlock` I bind the `Name` property of the `Person` class object that I have. `DataContext` is set using a `ViewModelLocator` class.

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="300" Width="300"
        Title="MVVM Light Application"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding Contact.Name}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In my `ViewModel`, I set the `Name` to `Tom` in the constructor, and change it when the button is clicked. I expect `Tom` to show up in the `TextBlock` when window is loaded (which it does), and to be changed to `Jane` when the button is clicked (which it doesn't).

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Person _contact = new Person();
    public Person Contact
    {
        get { return _contact; }
        set { Set(ref _contact, value); }
    }

    public RelayCommand ClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        Contact = new Person() { Name = "Tom" };
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        Contact.Name = "Jane";
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Contact.Name` does not trigger the `INotifyPropertyChanged.NotifyChanged` event as the Contact setter is not executed. You could fix this using by one of the following techniques:

**Implement INotifyPropertyChanged also in your model class**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name 
    { 
       get => _name; 
       set
       {
           _name = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, nameof(Name)); 
       }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Or wrap the PersonClass in a PersonViewModel**

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Person _person;

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public string Name 
    { 
       get => _person.Name; 
       set
       {
            var name = _person.Name;
            if (Set(ref name, value))
                _person.Name = name;
       }
    }
}
```

and in MainViewModel:

```
private PersonViewModel _contactViewModel
public PersonViewModel Contact
{
    get { return _contactViewModel ?? (_contactViewModel = new PersonViewModel(_contact)); }
}
```

**Or create a separate ContactName property in the MainViewModel**

... and using `ContactName` instead of `Contact.Name` in the binding and the Click event handler.

```
public string ContactName
{
    get { return _contact.Name; }
    set 
    {
        var name = _contact.Name;
        if (Set(ref name, value))
            _contact.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew that you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the Model, but was hoping I wouldn't have to, since I have more than just a couple of properties. Plus, polluting the Model with all that junk seems a bad practice.

Comment: I would have liked to use the second method, but it still doesn't update the GUI.

Comment: In the second method the problem is that setting `Contact.Name` doesn't even invoke the setter, so the setter in `ContactName` never gets called.

Comment: Yes, you have to Change the Click handler, top, to Set ContactName

Comment: But that that completely eliminates the need to have the `Contact` property, but I need it for other things than simply displaying data. But thanks for clearing up things.

Comment: Can I explicitly invoke the `Contact` setter?

Comment: I added another option (the second one) which might fit your needs better.